# I am unable to create an anonymous user in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-config

I have tried my best to an anonymous user in my `aspnet_Users` table by disallowing newly created user to pass through the login process. But still `aspnet_Users` table is showing the newly created user as `IsAnonymous = false`.

I have done my best to try to understand why my coding showing this kind of behaviour. I have done `AllowAnonymous enabled = true`, `Authentication mode=form` and many more but no success.

What is the reason of my failure? Please guide me.

Thanks

```
<asp:CreateUserWizard ID="CreateUserWizard1" runat="server"    
     OnCreatedUser="CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser">
    <WizardSteps>
        <asp:CreateUserWizardStep ID="CreateUserWizardStep1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" colspan="2">Sign Up for Your New Account</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">
                            <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">User Name:</asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right">
                                    <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" 
AssociatedControlID="Password">Password:</asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" 
TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" 
runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" ErrorMessage="Password is required." 
ToolTip="Password is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right">
                                    <asp:Label ID="ConfirmPasswordLabel" runat="server" 
AssociatedControlID="ConfirmPassword">Confirm Password:</asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="ConfirmPassword" runat="server" 
TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
ID="ConfirmPasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword" 
ErrorMessage="Confirm Password is required." ToolTip="Confirm Password is required." 
ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right">
                                    <asp:Label ID="EmailLabel" runat="server" 
AssociatedControlID="Email">E-mail:</asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="Email" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="EmailRequired" 
runat="server" ControlToValidate="Email" ErrorMessage="E-mail is required." ToolTip="E-mail   
is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right">
                                    <asp:Label ID="QuestionLabel" runat="server" 
AssociatedControlID="Question">Security Question:</asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="Question" runat="server">
</asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="QuestionRequired" 
runat="server" ControlToValidate="Question" ErrorMessage="Security question is required." 
ToolTip="Security question is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right">
                                    <asp:Label ID="AnswerLabel" runat="server" 
AssociatedControlID="Answer">Security Answer:</asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="Answer" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="AnswerRequired" 
runat="server" ControlToValidate="Answer" ErrorMessage="Security answer is required." 
ToolTip="Security answer is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" colspan="2">
                                    <asp:CompareValidator ID="PasswordCompare" 
runat="server" ControlToCompare="Password" ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword" 
Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="The Password and Confirmation Password must match." 
ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1"></asp:CompareValidator>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" colspan="2" style="color:Red;">
                                    <asp:Literal ID="ErrorMessage" runat="server" 
EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:CreateUserWizardStep>
                 <asp:WizardStep runat="server">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" colspan="2" class="auto-style1">These are 
Custom Fields</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" 
AssociatedControlID="Firstname">First name:</asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="Firstname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" 
AssociatedControlID="Lastname">Last name:</asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="Lastname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </asp:WizardStep>
                <asp:CompleteWizardStep ID="CompleteWizardStep1" runat="server">
                    
                </asp:CompleteWizardStep>
            </WizardSteps>
        </asp:CreateUserWizard>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
and in the web.config
<anonymousIdentification enabled="true"/>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name="SignalRChat" protection="All" path="/" timeout="60"/>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="myConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-3GI4IDE;Initial     
Catalog=aspnetdb;User ID=sa;Password=********"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<membership defaultProvider="MySqlLoginProvider">
<providers>
<add name="MySqlLoginProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"     
connectionStringName="myConnectionString" applicationName="VijayApp"/>
</providers>
</membership>
```

I tried enable AnonymousIdentification = true, authentication = form.

Comment: You should not be using the `sa` user in your application for security reasons. Create a user that has only the necessary permissions.

Comment: the WHOLE concept of a anonymous user is they in fact don't exist in your authentication system. In other words, to allow anonymous users means you don't need a user in the authentication system. As such, you actually will not create a user, and the instant you create such a user, they are NOT considered anonymous anymore!